# Center custom Font with canvas.DrawText()

Tags: android, xamarin, font-awesome

I have a custom font String (Font-Awesome Icon) and I want to draw it into a FloatingActionButton. For this reason I must convert the String to a Drawable like [this](https://gist.github.com/Y-brin/293c4f68470848df08ea).
The problem is that the icon is never centered, even if I try something like this:

```
public override void Draw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);
    float x = (canvas.Width / 2f) - (bounds.Width() / 2f)
    float y = (canvas.Height / 2f) - (bounds.Height() / 2f);
    canvas.DrawText(text, x, y, paint);
}
```

The result will be something like this:

[image: The icon on the FloatingActionButton is not centered]

I can't figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
If I do GetBounds, this is the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: instead of canvas.* use getBounds().*

Comment: @pskink Do you mean `canvas.GetClipBounds();` ?

Comment: no Drawable. getBounds(), also it should be float y = (canvas.Height / 2f) + (bounds.Height() / 2f);

Comment: @pskink I have `float y = (canvas.Height / 2f) - (bounds.Height() / 2f);` just read my code above. But I don't understand where to put `Drawable.GetBounds();`

Comment: use plus,  not minus,  also dont uset canvas size but drawable size

Comment: @pskink Look at the edited answer, the result is the following

Comment: did you change float y?

Comment: @pskink I changed the Minus in the float y to Plus

Comment: so your bounds are empty: bounds.Height() == 0, Log.d the bounds

Comment: @pskink I am sorry I posted the wrong picture. Just look at the newest screenshot in my post. Bounds are not 0 but it does not center the icon anyway.

Comment: Log.d two rects from: Drawable.getBounds() and Paint.getTextBounds()

Comment: here you have it: http://codeshare.io/HhBmb

Comment: and what? did it work?

Comment: @pskink If I set a Color to the Circle, it works, but if the Circle is Transparent, the Icon is no longer vertically centered. Thank you for your help, I think the rest should not be a problem.